# unable call function from another class on codeigniter 3.1

Tags: codeigniter, oop

I have two controller class
 A. datatraining.php 
 B. chisquare.php

when i call function from chisquare controller and I runs datatraining controller  I got error message like this :
[image]

```
class datatraining extends CI_Controller {

public function progress(){

            $path= __DIR__;
            $new_path= dirname($path,2);

            require_once(APPPATH.'controllers/chisquare.php'); //include controller
            $chisquare = new chisquare();  
            $chisquare->processnaivebayes();

}

class chisquare extends CI_Controller {
public function processnaivebayes(){
        ........
  }
}
```

anyone can help to resolve that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class chisquare extends datatraining {
public function processnaivebayes(){
    ........
 }
}
```

Try to extend second class with first class..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call processnaivebayes() function from datatraining class, you should extends chisquare :

```
class datatraining extends chisquare {
public function progress(){

            $path= __DIR__;
            $new_path= dirname($path,2);

            require_once(APPPATH.'controllers/chisquare.php'); //include controller
            $chisquare = new chisquare();  
            $chisquare->processnaivebayes();

}

class chisquare extends CI_Controller {
public function processnaivebayes(){
        ........
  }
}
```

Comment: i have try but i got error like this:   Fatal error: Class 'chisquare ' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\sentimenanalis\application\controllers\datatraining .php on line 4

Comment: Try to write the chisquare() function first then write datatraining() .

Answer (score 0):

Most important thing you have to consider that the name of the controller page should start from capital letter.

```
Datatraining.php
Chisquare.php
```

Save controller pages by above name.

And controller class also starts from capital letter.

```
class Datatraining extends CI_Controller {

public function progress(){
```

And

```
class Chisquare extends CI_Controller {
public function processnaivebayes(){
        ........
  }
}
```